# Is it bad if I try to answer a question based on recently learned material while providing the source?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've been on a learning streak for some time now, on fields regarding a few different communities here at Stack Overflow.

From time to time, a question will pop up that I feel I am able to answer, but I am not 100% sure because:

- I am new at the topic
- It is a "case by case" or "applied" type of question

So my question is:

How bad is it if I try and answer those questions while providing:

- how I am framing the problem + answer
- where I got the background from (citation/link)?

Comment: I'd say on a scale of 0 to bad, that would be on the 0 side. The worst thing that can happen is that you're wrong, someone else answers, then your answer may possibly be downvoted, but deleting or correcting said answer can alleviate that.

Comment: "whilst providing [1] [2]" That's the *best* way to answer questions, period. Don't let anybody tell you otherwise.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with being wrong. Almost all my first SO answers were wrong, but the kicker? I learned from all of them.

Comment: It isn't bad at all. The worst thing that could happen is that your info is wrong and that you're getting downvoted. However, that also means that you now know that your info is wrong, so you learned something from it. Some people may even comment why they think your info is wrong, which is even more useful to learn. If your answer is downvoted, you can still fix it, or you can delete it.

Comment: if you answer and youre wrong or only partially wrong most SO users will comment to help you understand why youre wrong, this allows you to learn at the same time as someone else, chances are if youre thinking it then the poster of the question could be thinking it too. and the best way to learn something is to try and teach someone else

Comment: **Shameless confession**: Once I tried answering question from API I had no knowledge of by searching and reading its docs.

Comment: This is how I learn things

Comment: Everyone really just _thinks_ they know the answer. If you feel confident enough to answer, it's okay if you feel less than 100% confident about it. Even people who are completely certain they are correct can still be wrong sometimes.

Comment: Cunningham's Law states "the best way to get the right answer on the internet is not to ask a question; it's to post the wrong answer." so you actually might be helping more than you think!

Comment: If in doubt, test the answer before posting.  I mean... if you TESTED it you know it works right?  If the answer isn't testable um well hmm I dunno maybe I don't answer the right kinds of questions?  I'd almost say if you can't test the answer then that's a whole other kind of worry.  You can at least quote an authoritative source or "read the docs" though right?  We're talking about stack overflow right?  I guess "Programmers" giving job behavior advice 5 years working experience may well help ... or not.  Test if possible else use best judgement.

Comment: I'm still getting upvotes from an answer I provided to an old question when I was a newbie.  It was a simple solution that had recently surfaced because of  a language change.  I happened to Google for an answer to my question, and found the new simple solution on the web, as well as the old SO question that only had older, more complicated answers. I was lucky to find the solution at the right time, but I did take the time to test it (very easy) and post it, and it's still providing a service to the community. That's part of what SO rewards.  Would it have been fairer to withhold the answer?

Comment: This is probably even more important if it is a rather rare topic and nobody else answered the question very well.  At worst case, your answer will help someone else find out a better answer, and at best case, you will end up at with the right answer because it was part of what you just learned.

Comment: This reminds me of someone in here who got a huge amount of rep, people didn't understand how he could get over the daily limit. He explained that he only answered question with bounties. He would read the question, search the internet and learn, then he was able to answer the question with material he just learned.

Comment: @TimyGiant said it best. As long as you're answering out of trying to help someone with what you believe is correct, go for it! Just be aware that if your answer is incorrect - or even substandard - you may get down voted. That's ok, because (1) the down vote is hopefully due to the right reasons, thus (2) you can simply delete it.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Sounds like a reasonable approach to me.  You're showing your work, and those are the kinds of answers that are appreciated.  At worst, someone's going to downvote and disagree with your solution, but if you present your facts and feel confident *enough* to answer the question, then there's no real problem that I can see.

Comment: Agreed. You are learning, and teaching is one of the best ways to learn. Trying not to treat it as a rep-based game, but actually helping people is one of the ways community is built. Good for you.

Comment: @holdenweb Not to mention, sometimes right after you learn something is the best time to share it with someone else who may be stuck right where you just were.  It's almost synergistic if I dare borrow a buzzword.

Comment: I've actually wrote bad answers. Deleted them, but also sometimes I just keep them available, because the answer is either a hack (which got downvoted) or the comments made for why it's wrong are more valuable than other answers :D

Answer (score 31):

Just a bit of advice on doing so, from someone who does a lot of closing/deleting

1. **Listen to what more experienced commenters say.** Sometimes you can learn a lot from attempting an answer and having a more experienced user come along and offer constructive criticism. Conversely, there's nothing more annoying than someone who sails in with an answer that has problems, and you leave them a comment and nothing happens. Feel free to debate in comments, but please listen to what commenters say (provided they're not ranting or insulting you).
2. **Be prepared to delete your bad answers.** There's no shame is doing this (I've done this myself quite a few times), but leaving a bad answer up is counterproductive. Keep SO clean!
3. **Don't be so enamored with your lessons/examples/tutorials.** Sometimes they do a good job of teaching you the fundamentals, but sometimes they fail to take the real world into account. In PHP, for example, there's a LOT of bad tutorials out there that never bother to teach SQL injection. I've had people actually argue their answers, with giant security holes, were perfectly fine. Don't confuse code that works with good code. They're not always the same thing.
4. **Don't give up!** You can learn a lot by reading and participating in SO. Don't take negative feedback as a reason to stop. But learn as you go. You'll be surprised how much you can learn just by hanging around. Too many people get moderated early on and give up.

Comment: +1 for the second bullet point. I can't tell you how many times I've seen new and seasoned users alike delete their answers. Deleting your answer isn't shameful, it's simply part of the normal SO lifecycle.

Comment: +1 for #4, because even saying "me culpa" and deleting a few bad answers just means you should come back an try again. It's *really hard* to get answer-banned. And don't feel that you have to delete every down-voted answer you have either. I've got a half-dozen or more that were downvoted, but I stand firmly behind my answer as being a good answer, just that someone (maybe the asker, maybe another answerer) went "I don't like this" and left no comments.

Answer (score 22):

There's no better way to learn than teaching someone else. If you feel that, hey, I can tackle this, then go for it. The worst that could happen is that you are downvoted. If the downvoter is civil, you'll find out why you were downvoted, so you can delete, correct, and undelete your post after that.

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty common for me to throw down an answer for a topic I know a little about. Usually, one of three things happens:

1. I'm right. Always a good thing. OP confirms that my answer solves their problem, so the answer gets verified.
2. I'm wrong, and when trying to fix my answer, I realize that I have no clue what I'm talking about. At that point, I'll delete my answer since someone else will have likely posted the correct answer by then, and misleading the OP is obviously not a good thing.
3. I'm wrong, but only by a little, and a minor edit/rewrite fixes the problem.

While it certainly sucks when the latter 2 possibilities happen, as the others have already pointed out, you'll learn from your mistakes. I've found when I do get a better understanding of the topic, that answer (deleted or not) helps reinforce my understanding.

Don't post wild, shot-in-the-dark answers that have no hope of being right, since you may end up confusing the OP. If you think you may be right though, post what you think will solve the problem, but be prepared to edit/delete if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The answers here so far are good, but I feel they've all missed an angle worth mentioning:

#### Every answer stands on its own merit.

One of the guiding principles we have here is that we don't care *who* posts the content: Good content is good content, and bad content is bad content. Sometimes someone with very low rep posts an excellent answer. Maybe they are new to the subject and studied it just for the purpose of answering the question; or maybe they are already an expert on the subject but only created their Stack Overflow account yesterday. Either way, if the answer is good, it deserves to be upvoted.

You mentioned citing your sources. This is a good idea regardless of whether you are a newbie or an established expert. In almost all cases, doing so improves the quality of the answer. I suppose it's possible to use a poor source, or use a good source but misinterpret it. In either of those cases, it's still valuable because it increases the chance someone will figure out exactly where you went wrong and explain it to you and whoever else reads your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what you should do.

None of us is 100% sure of our answer; that's why we have peer review.

If you're wrong, don't worry: you'll soon find out! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with doing that, but I would encourage you to question your motive. If your goal is to learn as much as possible, one of the best ways to do that is trying to use what you are learning to make something and teaching everything you learn along the way at the point learn it. If you skip the practicing part you are cutting yourself short. If you do all 3 of those at the same time, there is nothing wrong with teaching what you learn right at the point you learn it, provided you go back and update the information as you find out you did not totally understand it correctly. If you are not using what you are learning, it will take much longer before you find out you didn't understand it correctly, and therefore for you to update the information.

I would go a step further and say not only is there nothing wrong with this three pronged approach, but it actually helps you not only to learn better, but to teach better as well. There is something you gain by teaching something while you share the mindset of someone learning it.